# How can one use the apply function in pandas, while mapping the index across two different dataframes?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, apply

I am working with two pandas dataframes, "alignmentdf" and genbankdf.

alignmentdf contains a "DNA sequence alignment" as a dataframe, with the index as "taxonomy IDs" , these are just integers and the columns representing the codon numbers (as integers)

genbankdf contains data about "codon usage" for all the known taxonomies, therefore again with the index again being taxonomy IDs, and columns representing the codon frequencies per 1000 codons.

I want to create a new dataframe , df3 , that goes column by column in alignmentdf, looping through the rows, finding the corresponding index (i.e. taxonomic ID) in genbankdf, perform a calculation using values in genbankdf depending on what "codon" I have in alignmentdf, and output it to df3 , which is identical to alignmentdf in every way, but the codons are replaced with the calculated values.

I am new to the pandas module,  and I have done some tutorials using youtube and google searches - and I suspect I may have to use the ".apply" function but I am stumped as to the syntax I need to do what I want.

```
alignmentdf.head(5)
Out[38]: 
                                                       0    1    2    3    \
1076443  gi|1361169408|ref|WP_106366082.1| NAD(P)-depen...  ATG  AAA  GCC   
1076450  gi|1184222407|gb|OSC61482.1| alcohol dehydroge...  ATG  AAA  GCC   
110934   gi|947160360|ref|WP_055933433.1| MULTISPECIES:...  ATG  AAG  GCG   
1156841  gi|517339444|ref|WP_018514936.1| NAD(P)-depend...  ATG  AAA  GCC   
1156844  gi|517353486|ref|WP_018528978.1| NAD(P)-depend...  ATG  AAG  GCA   

         4    5    6    7    8    9   ...   345  346  347  348  349  350  351  \
1076443  CTG  CAA  TAC  CGC  GAG  ATC ...   GGG  CGC  GCG  GTG  ATC  CTG  CCG   
1076450  GTT  CAG  TAC  CGA  GCC  GTC ...   GGC  AGG  GCC  GTC  ATC  CTC  CCC   
110934   CTC  CAG  TAC  ACG  ACC  ATC ...   GGT  CGC  GCG  GTG  ATC  CTG  CCC   
1156841  GTC  CAG  TAC  CGG  GCC  GTC ...   GGC  CGC  GCG  GTG  ATC  CTG  CCG   
1156844  CTG  CAG  TAC  CGG  AGC  GTC ...   GGC  CGC  GCG  GTG  ATC  CTG  CCC   

         352  353  354  
1076443  ---  ---  TGA  
1076450  ---  ---  TGA  
110934   ---  ---  TGA  
1156841  ---  ---  TGA  
1156844  ---  ---  TGA  

[5 rows x 355 columns]
```

```
genbankdf.head(5)
Out[40]: 
        Division Assembly                                Species Organelle  \
Taxid                                                                        
939668   genbank      NaN  gamma proteobacterium SCGC AAA240-C10   genomic   
1938820  genbank      NaN                 Serratia sp. JKS000199   genomic   
768468   genbank      NaN  Dulcina sp. TB-2010 gill endosymbiont   genomic   
1549058  genbank      NaN               Bradyrhizobium sp. dxwr4   genomic   
477226   genbank      NaN                    Pseudomonas sp. SY6   genomic   

        Translation Table  # CDS  # Codons    GC%   GC1%   GC2%  ...     CGA  \
Taxid                                                            ...           
939668                 11      1       122  59.02  58.20  46.72  ...       1   
1938820                11   4700   1498667  61.12  63.10  42.49  ...    2886   
768468                 11      1       165  51.72  61.21  40.61  ...       0   
1549058                11      5       993  60.99  61.23  40.89  ...       1   
477226                 11      1       230  66.38  65.65  47.39  ...       1   

           CGG   AGT    AGC   AGA   AGG    GGT    GGC   GGA    GGG  
Taxid                                                               
939668       3     0      3     0     0      6      1     1      2  
1938820  14562  4320  35109  1770  1655  14372  79485  4405  17593  
768468       0     0      0     0     0     16      3     0      0  
1549058     10     2     11     1     3     21     53     8      6  
477226       3     0      6     0     1      1      8     0      4  

[5 rows x 75 columns]
```

I expect a dataframe (df3) that is indentical to alignment df, but the codon is replaced with a calculation of the "codon usage bias" informed by values in the row of genbankdf with the same index as alignmentdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) in loop because working with multiple columns:

```
print (alignmentdf)
                                                        0    1    2    3
1076443  gi|1361169408|ref|WP_106366082.1| NAD(P)-depen  ATG  AAA  GCC
1076450  gi|1184222407|gb|OSC61482.1| alcohol dehydroge  ATG  AAA  GCC
110934   gi|947160360|ref|WP_055933433.1| MULTISPECIES:  ATG  AAG  GCG
1156841  gi|517339444|ref|WP_018514936.1| NAD(P)-depend  ATG  AAA  GCC
1156800  gi|517353486|ref|WP_018528978.1| NAD(P)-depend  ATG  AAG  GCA  

print (genbankdf)
           ATG   AAA    GCC   AAG   GCG    GGT    GGC    GCA # Codons
110934       0     0      0     0     0     16      3      0      100
1076443      3     0      3     0     0      6      1      2      100
1156841     10     2     11     1     3    ---      8      6      100
1076450  14562  4320  35109  1770  1655  14372  79485  17593      ---
1156844     30     1      4     5     6      3      2      1      100
1156844      3     0      6     0     1      1      8      0       10
```

---

```
#remove duplicates in index, add missing values to genbankdf for correct mach
genbankdf = genbankdf[~genbankdf.index.duplicated()]
genbankdf = genbankdf.reindex(genbankdf.index.union(alignmentdf.index))
genbankdf['---'] = np.nan
print (genbankdf)
             ATG     AAA      GCC     AAG     GCG    GGT      GGC      GCA  \
110934       0.0     0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0     16      3.0      0.0   
1076443      3.0     0.0      3.0     0.0     0.0      6      1.0      2.0   
1076450  14562.0  4320.0  35109.0  1770.0  1655.0  14372  79485.0  17593.0   
1156800      NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN   
1156841     10.0     2.0     11.0     1.0     3.0    ---      8.0      6.0   
1156844     30.0     1.0      4.0     5.0     6.0      3      2.0      1.0   

        # Codons  
110934       100  
1076443      100  
1076450      ---  
1156800      NaN  
1156841      100  
1156844      100
```

---

```
s = pd.to_numeric(genbankdf['# Codons'], errors='coerce') * 1000
df3 = alignmentdf.copy()
for c in alignmentdf.columns[1:]:
    df3[c] = genbankdf.lookup(alignmentdf.index, alignmentdf[c])
    df3[c] = pd.to_numeric(df3[c], errors='coerce').div(s)
print (df3)
                                                      0        1        2  \
1076443  gi|1361169408|ref|WP_106366082.1| NAD(P)-depen  0.00003  0.00000   
1076450  gi|1184222407|gb|OSC61482.1| alcohol dehydroge      NaN      NaN   
110934   gi|947160360|ref|WP_055933433.1| MULTISPECIES:  0.00000  0.00000   
1156841  gi|517339444|ref|WP_018514936.1| NAD(P)-depend  0.00010  0.00002   
1156800  gi|517353486|ref|WP_018528978.1| NAD(P)-depend      NaN      NaN   

               3  
1076443  0.00003  
1076450      NaN  
110934   0.00000  
1156841  0.00011  
1156800      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your response jezrael, could I ask for some explanation of how your two code solutions work, and what the output of df3 will be?

Comment: @user1998510 - first do you run it? There was error or not?

Comment: I did run it and I got errors for both ; and because I am not advanced enough to understand exactly what is going on with  the code, the errors are also not making too much sense to me.
ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels for Dataframe.lookup code
KeyError: ('---', u'occurred at index 1') for Dataframe.apply code

Comment: for Dataframe.lookup code I get ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels

Comment: I also realised my question is perhaps not clear enough - for each value in alignmentdf (i.e. for example ATG of index key :1076443) , I wanted it to find the intersection value of 1076443 and ATG in genbankdf, and not just output the value, but perform a calculation with that value (using values in the same row, namely (ATG value / #codons)*1000 and put it as the new value in df3 at that position, which is why I thought I had to use the apply function,  but maybe it is still unnecessary.

Comment: @user1998510 - problem in my side, investigate. there is only formula `(ATG value / #codons)*1000 ` ? Or more complicated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191607/discussion-between-user1998510-and-jezrael).